# How to write a HOC in react which takes another hoc?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, higher-order-components

I am learning material UI by myself and came across this HOC pattern method withStyle HOC API, i tried implementing by myself with simple style(just string) to understand how this hoc(withStyle) function takes this hoc(named HigherOrderComponent)function works in code. 

this is App.js and rendering`<App/>` this in index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import customWithStyle  from './customWithStyle';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';


function HigherOrderComponent(props) {

  return <Button color={props}>Higher-order component</Button>;

}


const someStyle="primary";
export default customWithStyle(someStyle)(HigherOrderComponent);
```

And the code i tried writing is in customWithStyle.js file

```
 import React from 'react'
 const customWithStyle=(style)=>(Hoc)=>{
          //console.log(style);
         console.log(<Hoc/>)
         return  <Hoc props={style}/>
 }


export default customWithStyle ;
```

i am getting error

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
```

can some one help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way that i use Hoc was with class. Something like this will help you

```js
function HigherOrderComponent(props) {
   return (<div style={{color: props.color}}>this is the main component</div>)
}

const customWithStyle = style => WrappedComponent => {
 class HOC extends React.Component{
       render = () => (<WrappedComponent color={style}></WrappedComponent>);
        }
  
 return HOC;
};

const StyledComponent = customWithStyle("red")(HigherOrderComponent);

ReactDOM.render(<StyledComponent />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: thank you so much. returning the jsx element in function was not possible, that i was feeling it that the reason that we should use class.

Answer (score 0):

Use props.props within your HigherOrderComponent functional component for value of color attribute in Button Material component

Comment: thank you for replying, still same error. can we do all modification in customWithStyle.js itself.

Comment: Can you just console the props of HigherOrderComponent functional component? What value it will console..

Comment: Object { "$$typeof": Symbol(react.element), type: HigherOrderComponent(props)

Comment: The Hoc you created before you can use that Hoc as function within jsx. As eg <div>{HigherOrderComponent}</div>    it will work

Comment: Maybe its HOF not HOC what you created before.